# timezone api for the province of Yukon is returning incorrect results

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api, timezone

I believe the timezone api is giving me wrong offset values for Yukon. Using lat/long 60.7211871/-135.0568448, I get these offsets:

```
{
  "dstOffset": 0,
  "rawOffset": -28800,
  "status": "OK",
  "timeZoneId": "America/Vancouver",
  "timeZoneName": "Pacific Standard Time"
}
```

But the correct timezone should be UTC/GMT-7 hours which should give us a rawOffset of

```
{
  "dstOffset": 0,
  "rawOffset": -25200,
...
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Internet says PST is UTC-8 right now. UTC-7 (PDT) in summer.

Comment: Internet says it's UTC-7 year long. So, it should be Mountain Standard Time year round, UTC/GMT-7

Comment: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/canada/whitehorse

Comment: BTW this is new in the Yukon. They no longer observe DST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offset isn't the issue.  The issue is that the coordinates you gave, which are in Whitehorse, Yukon, Canada, are returning as part of the `America/Vancouver` time zone instead of `America/Whitehorse`.

I checked and get the same results as you do.  I also get Vancouver for locations near Dawson City, which is also incorrect now.

As you pointed out, this is all related to [recent changes in time zones in Yukon](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/yukon-canada-permanent-dst.html).  Previously, the IANA time zones `America/Whitehorse` and `America/Dawson` were in the same logical time as `America/Vancouver`, but since the change they are now better grouped with `America/Creston`, `America/Dawson_Creek`, and `America/Fort_Nelson`.

The reliable open-source [Timezone Boundary Builder](https://github.com/evansiroky/timezone-boundary-builder) project has this correct.  It appears, however, that the Google Maps Time Zone API is not using this source but rather their own - and that it has not been updated for this recent change.

I have [filed a bug with Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173435583).  You can star that issue to get updates.

You might also try [one of the alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086964/634824).

---

**UPDATE:**  Google has fixed this issue.